# How to display the table from nested json array in angular?

Tags: angular, angular6, angular5, angular7

I'm using angular 7 and I want to display the nested json datas in the table.
My Json structure:

```
{
  "id": "1",
  "referenceNumber": "P123",
  "supplierNote": "My Notes",
  "internalNote": "Your notes",
  "purchaseOrderProducts": [
   {
      "purchaseId": "p1",
      "quantity": 1000,
   },
   {
      "purchaseId": "p2",
      "quantity": 500,
   }
 ]
}
```

I want to display the value "**purchaseId**" and "**quantity**" in the table  using angular.

Answer (score 0):

```
Use *ngFor in the html for the above
assuming the above json is an Object purchase

<table>
<div *ngFor="let obj of purchase.purchaseOrderProducts">
<tr>{{obj.purchaseId}}</tr>
<tr>{{obj.quantity}}</tr>
</div>
</table>
```

Comment: Facing the problem "Cannot read property 'purchaseOrderProducts' of undefined"

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please edit your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display only `purchaseid` and `quantity` information then you can use `*ngFor` directive to loop over the  `purchaseOrderProducts` array and display the data.

HTML will look like below  :

```
<table bordar="2">
    <tr>
        <th>purchaseId</th>
        <th>quantity</th>
    </tr>
    <tr *ngFor="let data of arrObj?.purchaseOrderProducts">
        <td>    {{data.purchaseId}}</td>
        <td>{{data.quantity}}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Here is the working example :

**https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dfsfpr**

Comment: Thanks. But how to bind the value using formControlName in table?

Comment: those values you want to bind with formControl ?

Comment: You have to use `formArray`

Comment: "<form [formGroup]="myForm"> 
<table formArrayName="products">
      <tbody *ngFor="let item of myForm.controls.products.controls; let i=index">
          <tr  [formGroupName]="i" >
          <td><input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="purchaseId" /></td>
          <td><input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="quantity" /></td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
</table>
</form>" I used this way ..But not able to display all values. Kindly help me to solve this